# iOS Browser App with custom context menu option

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios4

I am looking for some iOS ( iphone/ipad) samples for below features:

1. A native iOS app ( iphone / ipad) for web browsing with basic features.
2. I want to hookup Custom context menu options ( in addition to cut/paste standard options) on text selection in the browser.

**edit #1** I came across SVWebViewController lib. It provides ability to add inline browser to the app:-
https://github.com/samvermette/SVWebViewController

please share any links or hints that you can provide that I can look at before I begin writing my app.

**edit #2**: found this video helpful for browser app. Its a quick walkthrough for coding a UIWebView. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yICZb91Poxs

this link also - http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2011/05/21/tutorial-building-a-web-browser-with-uiwebview-part-1/

thanks.

Comment: As the author of SVWebViewController, I'd like to mention that the intent of it isn't to "create a browser-like app", but to add an inline browser to your app (which has a main purpose other than browsing the web). For instance, a Twitter client app would use it to open links without leaving the app.

Comment: thanks for correction. I reflected the same in my post.

Comment: @samvermette ...any tips ?  i am getting following link errors building sample for SVWebViewController   
      "__Block_object_dispose", referenced from:      ___destroy_helper_block_1 in SVWebViewController.o__NSConcreteStackBlock$non_lazy_ptr in SVWebViewController.o

Comment: i installed sdk for ios 4 that resolved the link error.

Comment: Ah, didn't think about that. Probably should mention somewhere that it requires iOS 4 SDK. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a great resource for your second question.
http://www.icab.de/blog/2010/07/11/customize-the-contextual-menu-of-uiwebview/